# Xamarin Forms TemplateBinding to Command In BasePage

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a BasePage created using ControlTemplates that contains a loading overlay for each child to use - This overlay has a "cancel" button on it, but for some reason I can't get ICommands to execute when I tap the buttons. Clicked events work fine but I'd like to understand what the problem is with Commands.

I researched the issue and found I should be binding using Command="{TemplateBinding MyCommand}" since my content is within a ControlTemplate but still no luck, however I am also binding the Text property and this is working fine, so I'm a bit confused.

Here's a cut down version of what I've hacked together.

Here's my BasePage XAML with the button in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage x:Name="this" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:ShoppingListNEW.MarkupExtensions" xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ShoppingListNEW.Views" x:Class="ShoppingListNEW.Pages.BasePage">
    <ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
           <Grid Padding="0" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout.Padding>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,30,0,0"/>
                    </StackLayout.Padding>
                    <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                        <StackLayout RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </StackLayout>
                <AbsoluteLayout IsVisible="False" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="loading" BackgroundColor="#85000000" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
                    <ActivityIndicator Color="Lime" Scale="2" IsRunning="true" IsEnabled="true" IsVisible="true" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.4" />
                    <Button IsVisible="True" Text="{TemplateBinding MyTextLabel}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5" Command="{TemplateBinding MyCommand}" />
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </Grid>  
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage>
```

And here's the C# for that BasePage:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ShoppingListNEW.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ShoppingListNEW.Pages
{
    public partial class BasePage : ContentPage
    {
        public string MyTextLabel { get; set; } = "This Works";
        public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }
        public BasePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                Console.Write("But this doesn't work :(");
            });
        }

        public void ShowHideLoading(bool showhide, bool allowCancel = false)
        {
            var loadingLayout = (AbsoluteLayout)GetTemplateChild("loading");
            var cancelButton = loadingLayout.FindByName<Button>("btnCancel");
            cancelButton.IsVisible = allowCancel;
            loadingLayout.IsVisible = showhide;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try moving initialisation of your `MyCommand` before the call for `InitializeCompontent`. I suspect that when the binding is being resolved (when calling `InitializeCompontent`) the command is not there yet and therefore it resolves to `null` - just a guess though.

Comment: Agree with this, just move that work string property initial to ctor and if didn't work you may should do bonding before initializeCompontent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Thanks to Mikolaj Kieres for the answer, it was a simple case of initialising the Command earlier so I moved it up above the InitializeComponent and that kicked it into life. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On your ControlTemplate binding, please use the following code:

```
 <Button
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                    Command="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.MyCommand}"
                    IsVisible="True"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.MyTextLabel}" />
```

I use your code to create simple that you can take a look, please don't set AbsoluteLayout IsVisible="False".

```
 <ContentPage.ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid Padding="0">
            <StackLayout>

                <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <StackLayout
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                               Property=Height}"
                        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                              Property=Width}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </StackLayout>
            <AbsoluteLayout
                x:Name="loading"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                BackgroundColor="#85000000">
                <ActivityIndicator
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.4"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                    IsEnabled="true"
                    IsRunning="true"
                    IsVisible="true"
                    Scale="2"
                    Color="Lime" />
                <Button
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                    Command="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.MyCommand}"
                    IsVisible="True"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.MyTextLabel}" />
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.ControlTemplate>

public partial class Page19 : ContentPage
{
    public Page19()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new Viewmodel1();
    }       
}

public class Viewmodel1:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _MyTextLabel;
    public string MyTextLabel
    {
        get { return _MyTextLabel; }
        set
        {
            _MyTextLabel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyTextLabel");
        }
    }
    public RelayCommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    public Viewmodel1()
    {
        MyCommand = new RelayCommand(method);
        MyTextLabel = "this is test";            
    }
    private void method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is test!");
    }     
}
```